# JNDI & AD bind error when special characters like &,%,$ present in UserDN

Tags: ldap, bind, jndi

I have implemented a java code which connects to the given host ip with username and password of the AD server.(using JNDI)

Now when I use a username which has no special character it works fine. But when I use symbols like $, #, &, etc in the username it gives me `Auth. Error`.

I am surprised to see this because &,$, and # are not used in `userdn` format by AD.

Can anyone explain what the problem and what can be the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure (I have very little information to judge), but there may be a problem with the "7-bit-check-plugin". It is a LDAP plugin, which is responsible for rejection of data that are coded with more than 7 bits. This includes characters as %, $, # as well as some German characters, middle and east European characters, etc.

Please try to check if you have enabled 7-bit-check-plugin. If so, try to disable it and use that data again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will surely check that. I need to check it on AD server side right?. I have tested same with Openldap on linux there it works without any problem.

Comment: Sure, check the "AD server side". Wish best luck.